# How to add like counter Android Studio Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[this is the database link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBF3T.jpg) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBF3T.jpg)can anybody help me to add a like counter to this.please please 
it should display the no:of likes and decease it when like is taken back
my java code is below

```
 private void onLikeClicked(View v) {
    boolean isLiked = !btnLike.isSelected();
    final String currentUserKey = User.currentKey();

    DatabaseReference likes = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(Const.kDataLikeKey);
    DatabaseReference curLike = likes.child(mPostRef.getKey()).child(currentUserKey).child("liked");

    // update Model
    curLike.setValue(isLiked);

    // update UI
    btnLike.setSelected(isLiked);
}
```

**This increment like count but doesn't decrements it** i want it to get decremented when clicked back

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not entirely clear but if you are trying to make a functionality like social media post where users can like and unlike a post the this can help.

**Data Structure**

```
Post-> postId -> likes -> 1 
              ...
```

**You can divide it in three parts:**

1. To display number of likes for a post , `postId` & current user, `userId1`, has liked your post or not

   ```
   public void displayNumberOfLikes(String postId, String currentUserId){
       DatabaseReference likesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child('Post').child(postId);
       likesRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
           @Override
           public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
               if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                   long numOfLikes = 0;
                   if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("likes")){
                       numOfLikes = dataSnapshot.child("likes").getValue(Long.class);
                   }

                   //Populate numOfLikes on post i.e. textView.setText(""+numOfLikes)
                   //This is to check if the user has liked the post or not
                   btnLike.setSelected(dataSnapshot.hasChild(userId));
               }
           }

           @Override
           public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

           }
       });
   }
   ```
2. On Like Clicked

   ```
   public void onLikeClicked(View v, String postId, String userId){
       DatabaseReference likesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child('Post').child(postId).child("likes");
       likesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){
           @Override
           public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
               long numLikes = 0;
               if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                   numLikes = dataSnapshot.getValue(Long.class);
               }
               boolean isLiked = btnLike.isSelected();
               if(isLiked){
                  //If already liked then user wants to unlike the post
                  likesRef.set(numLikes-1);
               }else {
                  //If not liked already then user wants to like the post
                  likesRef.set(numLikes+1);
               }
           }

           @Override
           public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

           }
       });
   }
   ```

This way you can make your user like and unlike a post and display total number of likes. 
Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you sir but this is having a small issue when i unlike it that node is deleted..so say if 2 users have liked it and when one of then press back(unlike) then the whole node is deleted..actually i just want to subtract 1 from the whole like count when the user pres like button again

Comment: Can you add your db structure in the question? It would be helpful if you explain the exact scenario using actual data.

Comment: posts
 -LGEF7JPjhzROruGct_E
   -image: 
  -likecnt
    -likecnt: 
  -likes: 
  -time: 
  -user:

Comment: @AryaPrabagar This is not helping. Can put it in a fair image with some explanation

Comment: sir i have added a image link

Comment: i have tried the code when i click like/unlike the counting goes to infinity..ie for +1 likes it keeps on counting and never stops

Comment: Sorry I implemented addValueEventListener instead of addListenerForSingleValueEvent. I have corrected the answer.

Comment: the code "numLikes = dataSnapshot.getValue(Long.class);" gives me an error so i have changed the code to public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                long numLikes = 0;
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    boolean isLiked = !btnLike.isSelected();
                    if (isLiked) {
                        //If already liked then user wants to unlike the post
                        likes.setValue(numLikes - 1);                                                             but i cannot get the value from firebase databse

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.lang.Long.longValue()' on a null object reference
                      at me.android.prj.frdes.adapters.StoryViewHolder$2.onDataChange(StoryViewHolder.java:372)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have added the null pointer check for dataSnapshot in function displayNumberOfLikes.