# Want to add the like counter in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

When I was clicking on like button the like value increase in all the childs but I want it to increase in the particular child

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(final int clickItemIndex) {
    databaseReference.child("Stories").orderByChild("show").equalTo("1").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
              String like = dataSnapshot1.child("like").getValue(String.class);
              int ll = Integer.parseInt(like);
              int l2 = ll + 1;
              String like2 = String.valueOf(l2);
                    databaseReference.child("Stories").child(dataSnapshot1.getKey()).child("like").setValue(like2);
          }
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError){
      }


 });
}
```

I took reference from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51088229/how-to-add-like-counter-android-studio-firebase) link please help me out

Comment: simply get that child id and update its value like ref.child("stories").child(id).child("like").setValue("1");

Comment: child id are push Id how do I take refernce of pushId they are randomly generated

Comment: you can generate your own id's using UUID Random id's and add them to your object

Comment: Okay but how does it solve my problem because I need to take reference of that UUID and ow can I take reference of random UUID.

Answer (score 0):

On Item Click get the Complete Object of Store..
Then ,

**Model Class or DataClass Structure.**

```
Story->date
     ->like
    ->show
    ->story
    ->userName
    ->storyId
```

FireBase Database Structure:

```
stories->
       ->storyId->
         Story->date
         ->like
        ->show
        ->story
        ->userName
        ->storyId
```

now simply query using object Id. and add 1 to it.

@Override
public void onItemClick(final int clickItemIndex) {

```
    databaseReference.child("Stories").orderByChild("show").equalTo("1").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
              String like = dataSnapshot1.child("like").getValue(String.class);
              int ll = Integer.parseInt(like);
              int l2 = ll + 1;
              String like2 = String.valueOf(l2);
                    databaseReference.child("Stories").child(story.getStoryId()).child("like").setValue(like2);
          }
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError){
      }


 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(final int clickItemIndex) {
    databaseReference.child("Stories").orderByChild("show").equalTo("1").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
              String like = dataSnapshot1.child("like").getValue(String.class);
              int ll = Integer.parseInt(like);
              int l2 = ll + 1;
              String like2 = String.valueOf(l2);

           Map userInfo = new HashMap();
           userInfo.put("like", like2);
           databaseReference.child("Stories").child(dataSnapshot1.getKey()).updateChildren(userInfo);
          }
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError){
      }


 });
}
```

Hope It's help full.